# Parsing/Writing SysML v2?

Tags: python-3.x, sysml

I'm trying to find an existing parser (preferably in Python) to write and read SysML v2.

The official Github repo by SysML v2 Submission Team (SST) has placed some examples online already (For instance https://github.com/Systems-Modeling/SysML-v2-Release/blob/master/sysml/src/examples/Vehicle%20Example/VehicleUsages.sysml ), but I'm unable to get the Eclipse Plugin running properly. (Nothing is shown in the preview windows, no error message either).

There's a repo for the SysML-v2-API-Python-Client which I installed and executed the given sample code (https://github.com/Systems-Modeling/SysML-v2-API-Python-Client), but all I'm getting is this message:

```
$ python3.8 Test1.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 159, in _new_conn
    conn = connection.create_connection(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 84, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 74, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 665, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 387, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1256, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1302, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1251, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1011, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 951, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 187, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 171, in _new_conn
    raise NewConnectionError(
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f9492d1b9a0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Test1.py", line 38, in <module>
    api_response = api_instance.delete_branch_by_project_and_id(
  File "/home/qohelet/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sysml_v2_api_client-2021.post9-py3.8.egg/sysml_v2_api_client/api/branch_api.py", line 62, in delete_branch_by_project_and_id
  File "/home/qohelet/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sysml_v2_api_client-2021.post9-py3.8.egg/sysml_v2_api_client/api/branch_api.py", line 144, in delete_branch_by_project_and_id_with_http_info
  File "/home/qohelet/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sysml_v2_api_client-2021.post9-py3.8.egg/sysml_v2_api_client/api_client.py", line 364, in call_api
  File "/home/qohelet/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sysml_v2_api_client-2021.post9-py3.8.egg/sysml_v2_api_client/api_client.py", line 181, in __call_api
  File "/home/qohelet/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sysml_v2_api_client-2021.post9-py3.8.egg/sysml_v2_api_client/api_client.py", line 431, in request
  File "/home/qohelet/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sysml_v2_api_client-2021.post9-py3.8.egg/sysml_v2_api_client/rest.py", line 256, in DELETE
  File "/home/qohelet/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sysml_v2_api_client-2021.post9-py3.8.egg/sysml_v2_api_client/rest.py", line 163, in request
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/request.py", line 75, in request
    return self.request_encode_url(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/request.py", line 97, in request_encode_url
    return self.urlopen(method, url, **extra_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/poolmanager.py", line 330, in urlopen
    response = conn.urlopen(method, u.request_uri, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 747, in urlopen
    return self.urlopen(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 747, in urlopen
    return self.urlopen(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 747, in urlopen
    return self.urlopen(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 719, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 436, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /projects/project_id_example/branches/branch_id_example (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f9492d1b9a0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
```

Am I supposed to have anything running? Is there anywhere a tutorial or manual on how to use it?

Or are there any other parsers out there?

Answer (score 0):

There are no parsers currently available for Python. The API Python Client is an example implementation to interact with the Pilot Server API Implementation. You would need to run the server to interact with the API using the python client.

Comment: What's the Pilot Server API Implementation and how to run it?